# matplotlib customize linecolor and line type cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a python class to produce a plot using the parameter that is suitable for my purpose (Elsevier paper) now I've read [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html) that is possible compute a cycle between several colors and several linestyle,

In my class I' using a slightly different syntax for setting the rcParam :

```
  myparams = {
            'patch.linewidth' : '0.5',
            'patch.facecolor' : '#348ABD',  # blue
            'patch.edgecolor' : 'EEEEEE',
            'patch.antialiased' : True,
            'font.size': self.parameters['fontsize'],
            'xtick.major.size' : 0.1,
            'xtick.minor.size' : 0.025,
            'axes.edgecolor': self.parameters['box'] ,   
            'axes.linewidth': 1,   # BOX width
            'axes.xmargin': 0,    
            'axes.ymargin': 0,     
            'axes.labelcolor': self.parameters['axeslabel'],     
            'axes.axisbelow': True,   
            'xtick.color': self.parameters['xtickcolor'],                  # doesn't affect the text
            'ytick.color': self.parameters['ytickcolor'],                  # doesn't affect the text 
            'axes.prop_cycle': self.colors( self.parameters['palette'] ) , 
            'grid.linestyle': '--', 
            'grid.alpha': '1',
            'grid.linewidth' : 1,
            'grid.color' : self.parameters['gridcolor'],
            'font.family': self.parameters['font'] ,
            'legend.edgecolor' : self.parameters['legendEdgeColor'],
            'legend.fancybox'  : False,
            'legend.borderpad' : 0.4 ,
            'legend.fontsize'  : self.parameters['legendfontsize'], 
            'legend.loc'       : 'best',
            'legend.framealpha': 1 
            }

         plt.rcParams.update(myparams)
```

where

```
self.colors( self.parameters['palette'] ) =  "cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62'] )"
```

now I would like to use (as reported in the link) a cycler on the color together with a cycler on the linestyle .. could some body help how can I got this with the syntax tat I'm using  ?

**EDIT** 
Thanks for reply ! 
Well .. honestly I don't know which is the difference !

but for example i would like to combine a cycle like this :

```
cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62'] )
```

with a cycle linestyle `['-', '--', ':', '-.']` first color 1st linetype .. 4th color
4 linetype , 5th color (since there is just 4 line type) 1 linetype again .. and proceeding like this ... but I'm open to learn other possibility ... for example I know that I can define the dashes space between two segment of line and so on .. but lets doing one thing at time

Comment: You can "multiply" or "add" cycles. How exactly would you like to combine the two cyclers?

Comment: I don't have time to give an answer right now, but I suggest you read [the tutorial about cyclers](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "add" a color cycler to linestyle cycler. Since you can only add two cyclers of same length, in order to achieve the requirement *"first color 1st linetype .. 4th color 4 linetype , 5th color (since there is just 4 line type) 1 linetype again"* one would need to double the linestyles.

Then you can create a cycler for colors and another one for the doubled list of linestyles and attach it to the `'axes.prop_cycle'` rcParameter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ["crimson", "gold", "indigo", "limegreen", "black", "lightseagreen",
          "orange", "darkorchid"]
linestyles = ['-', '--', ':', '-.']

cycle = plt.cycler("color", colors) + plt.cycler("linestyle", linestyles+linestyles)

myparams = {'axes.prop_cycle': cycle}
plt.rcParams.update(myparams)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(16):
    ax.plot([0,1],[i,i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

In general, see the [tutorial about cyclers](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) in the matplotlib documentation.